# SQL Server: how to update tables based on columns that are returned from a query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have a query that finds all the tables, across all my databases, with a given "keyword" search:

```
CREATE TABLE #tblTEMP1
(
     DBaseName VARCHAR(100), 
     TableSchema VARCHAR(50), 
     TableName VARCHAR(100), 
     ColumnName VARCHAR(100), 
     DataType VARCHAR(100),
     CharMaxLength VARCHAR(100) 
)

EXEC sp_MSForEachDB @command1 = 'USE [?];
    INSERT INTO #tblTEMP1 
        SELECT
            Table_Catalog, Table_Schema, Table_Name,
            Column_Name, Data_Type, Character_Maximum_Length
        FROM 
            INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
        WHERE 
            COLUMN_NAME like ''%password%'''

SELECT * FROM #tblTEMP1

DROP TABLE #tblTEMP1
```

How do I utilise the above query to actually `UPDATE` the columns it returns? Yes, I am trying to standardise every "user" table's password column with a single value, for example.

Comment: what do you want to `change` or `update` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, next approach may help. It's based on your statement, using `sp_MSForEachDB` undocumented procedure. Temporary table is not needed, just generate and execute a dynamic statement.

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachDB @command1 = '
    IF ''?'' NOT IN (''master'', ''model'', ''msdb'', ''tempdb'') BEGIN
        USE [?];

        DECLARE @stm nvarchar(max)
        SET @stm = N''''

        SELECT @stm = CONCAT(
            @stm,
            N''UPDATE '',
            QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA),
            N''.'',
            QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME),
            N'' SET '',
            QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME),
            N'' = ''''your_varchar_value''''; ''
        )
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
        WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE ''password%''

        PRINT @stm
        EXEC (@stm)
    END
'
```

Comment: Yes. This makes sense. Create the UPDATE statement on the fly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `sys.databases` to get the list of all databases.

```
  GO

  select * into #dbname from (SELECT * FROM sys.databases) as db

  select * from #dbname

  GO
```

Then you may use `cursor` to loop through each database and get your task done.